# Extracting specific values from column based on other column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
d1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             Stock = c("Stock 1","Stock 1","Stock 1",
                       "Stock 2","Stock 2","Stock 2","Stock 3","Stock 3",
                       "Stock 3"),
          Column.1 = c("...","...","...","...",
                       "...","...","...","...","..."),
          Column.2 = c("...","...","...","...",
                       "...","...","...","...","..."),
             Value = c(1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
)
```

| Stock | Column 1 | Column 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stock 1 | ... | ... | 1 |
| Stock 1 | ... | ... | 1 |
| Stock 1 | ... | ... | 1 |
| Stock 2 | ... | ... | 0.5 |
| Stock 2 | ... | ... | 0.5 |
| Stock 2 | ... | ... | 0.5 |
| Stock 3 | ... | ... | 0.2 |
| Stock 3 | ... | ... | 0.2 |
| Stock 3 | ... | ... | 0.2 |

But with 2000 stocks. Basically each stock has the same value in the given column. I would like to extract this value for each stock and put it in another data frame which is a list of stocks with different variables that looks like this:

```
d2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             Stock = c("Stock 1", "Stock 2", "Stock 3", "Stock 4", "Stock 5"),
        Variable.1 = c("y", "y", "y", "y", "y"),
        Variable.2 = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x"),
             Value = c("1", "0.5", "0.2", "...", "...")
)
```

| Stock | Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stock 1 | y | x | 1 |
| Stock 2 | y | x | 0.5 |
| Stock 3 | y | x | 0.2 |
| Stock 4 | y | x | ... |
| Stock 5 | y | x | ... |

How do I do this? :)

Edit: There are other columns than the one I want to extract the data from. :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the first data set you posted is called `d1`, and the second you posted is called `d2`. The [`unique`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) function will remove duplicate elements from your first data.frame.

```
merge(d2, unique(d1[,c("Stock", "Value")]))

    Stock Variable1 Variable2 Value
1 Stock 1         y         x   1.0
2 Stock 2         y         x   0.5
3 Stock 3         y         x   0.2
```

If you want to keep all rows from `d2`, even if there is not a match in `d1`, you can specify `all.x = TRUE` in the call to `merge.

```
merge(d2, unique(d1[,c("Stock", "Value")]), all.x = TRUE)

    Stock Variable1 Variable2 Value
1 Stock 1         y         x   1.0
2 Stock 2         y         x   0.5
3 Stock 3         y         x   0.2
4 Stock 4         y         x    NA
5 Stock 5         y         x    NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it didn't work. I have more columns in the first data frame, could that be a problem? Maybe I should have shown this in the question more clearly. I will update it to show how it looks.

Comment: If I understand you, you just want `unique` to work on the `Stock` and `Value` columns? If so, my edit should do that

Comment: I must have done something wrong before but now it worked! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try `merge` like below

```
> merge(df2, unique(df1), all.x = TRUE)
   Stock Variable1 Variable2 Value
1 Stock1         y         x   1.0
2 Stock2         y         x   0.5
3 Stock3         y         x   0.2
4 Stock4         y         x    NA
5 Stock5         y         x    NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Stock = c("Stock1", "Stock1", "Stock1", "Stock2",
"Stock2", "Stock2", "Stock3", "Stock3", "Stock3"), Value = c(1,
1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-9L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(Stock = c("Stock1", "Stock2", "Stock3", "Stock4",
"Stock5"), Variable1 = c("y", "y", "y", "y", "y"), Variable2 = c("x",
"x", "x", "x", "x")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```